# What to put for the $destinationPath when outside the public_path for a file upload in Laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

I'm trying to add the ability to upload a photo via a Laravel form. However, I seem to be a little bit outside of the normal use cases for getting it configured.

My `laravel` directory is actually outside of my main web directory, and for certain URI's, it uses an Apache `mod_alias` to redirect it to use the Laravel Framework. All of my css, js and images exist in the main web directory, and all of my laravel files and directory exist in its own separate directory. With that said, the location I want to be able to upload photos to is

```
/html/images/profile-photos
```

while my laravel app lives in

```
/laravel/...
```

In the controller for my form, I have

```
$photo = Input::file('photo');
if ($photo->isValid()) {
    $destinationPath = '/html/images/profile-photos/';
    $filename = $user->id;    //There might be a separate error in not including the file extension here?
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $filename);
}
```

But when I attempt to upload an image with the form, I get the error

```
Unable to create the "/html/images/profile-photos/" directory
```

By the looks of it, it appears it might not be going to the actual `/html` directory, but might still be stuck in the `/laravel` one. Is there a way to go about getting it stored in the intended location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. As soon as I posted this question, I realized my root directory was actually one step back. It had to be

```
'/root/html/images/profile-pictures'
```

As soon as you say it's broken, it fixes itself...